# remove the holes in an image by average values of surrounding pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, interpolation

[image: Gray Scale Image with Holes]

can any one please help me in filling these black holes by values taken from neighboring non-zero pixels.
thanks

Comment: Duplicate on DSP: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/2803/590

Comment: Solving that: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23794/interpolation-optimization-problem would do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a file on Matlab file exchange, - [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551) that does exactly what you want. The author explains why and in which cases it is better than Delaunay triangulation.

Answer (score 8):

One nice way to do this is to is to solve the [linear heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation). What you do is fix the "temperature" (intensity) of the pixels in the good area and let the heat flow into the bad pixels. A passable, but somewhat slow, was to do this is repeatedly average the image then set the good pixels back to their original value with `newImage(~badPixels) = myData(~badPixels);`.

I do the following steps:

1. Find the bad pixels where the image is zero, then dilate to be sure we get everything
2. Apply a big blur to get us started faster
3. Average the image, then set the good pixels back to their original
4. Repeat step 3
5. Display

You could repeat averaging until the image stops changing, and you could use a smaller averaging kernel for higher precision---but this gives good results:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
numIterations = 30;
avgPrecisionSize = 16; % smaller is better, but takes longer

% Read in the image grayscale:
originalImage = double(rgb2gray(imread('c:\temp\testimage.jpg')));

% get the bad pixels where  = 0 and dilate to make sure they get everything:
badPixels = (originalImage == 0);
badPixels = imdilate(badPixels, ones(12));

%# Create a big gaussian and an averaging kernel to use:
G = fspecial('gaussian',[1 1]*100,50);
H = fspecial('average', [1,1]*avgPrecisionSize);

%# User a big filter to get started:
newImage = imfilter(originalImage,G,'same');
newImage(~badPixels) = originalImage(~badPixels);

% Now average to
for count = 1:numIterations
   newImage = imfilter(newImage, H, 'same');
   newImage(~badPixels) = originalImage(~badPixels);
end

%% Plot the results
figure(123);
clf;

% Display the mask:
subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(badPixels);
axis image
title('Region Of the Bad Pixels');

% Display the result:
subplot(1,2,2);
imagesc(newImage);
axis image
set(gca,'clim', [0 255])
title('Infilled Image');

colormap gray
```

But you can get a similar solution using `roifill` from the image processing toolbox like so:

```
newImage2 = roifill(originalImage, badPixels);

figure(44);
clf;
imagesc(newImage2);
colormap gray
```

notice I'm using the same badPixels defined from before.

Answer (score 2):

To fill one black area, do the following:

1) Identify a sub-region containing the black area, the smaller the better. The best case is just the boundary points of the black hole.

2) Create a Delaunay triangulation of the non-black points in inside the sub-region by:

```
 tri = DelaunayTri(x,y); %# x, y (column vectors) are coordinates of the non-black points.
```

3) Determine the black points in which Delaunay triangle by:

```
[t, bc] = pointLocation(tri, [x_b, y_b]); %# x_b, y_b (column vectors) are coordinates of the black points
tri = tri(t,:);
```

4) Interpolate:

```
v_b = sum(v(tri).*bc,2); %# v contains the pixel values at the non-black points, and v_b are the interpolated values at the black points.
```